# How to create a numpy array with float values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am wanting to create a numpy 2D array in which every element is a tuple of float values. I was trying to use `np.range` and `np.arange` but didn't succeed. May I know of a concise way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: “but didn’t succeed.” Can you tell us what happened? Your post is extremely vague and broad.

Comment: you could well use `np.arange`, just change the shape afterwards, e.g. `a = np.arange(3,7)` and then `a.shape = (2,2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty([2, 2], dtype = float)
print(a)
```

Output:.

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Considering the question is tagged Python 3, using Python 2 syntax in an answer seems inappropriate.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica sorry not have python3 installed. Point accepted.

Comment: Thanks. So ```np.empty``` creates a ```2 x 2``` array where each element is a float?

Comment: @RishiBansal You should modify your answer, then... Even if the post weren’t tagged Python 3, that should still be the default.

Comment: @trickymaverick yes each element is float.